# Is it more efficient to read from an Excel file or an CSV file?

Tags: java, excel, csv

I need to write a quick program (using Java since its the only language I am really comfortable with) that takes an Excel file (or CSV) and parces through the data adding information that might be missing.

The problem Im having is that I cant decide how to start, it feels like manipulating an Excel file would be easier but reading through a CSV file would be really simple.

Any insight on problems that might come up or maybe a third solution that I'm ignoring.

The excel document is basically just a mini audited database of printer IPs, names, manufacturers, and locations.

Edit: General consensus seems to be that CSV is a lot more easy to manipulate and since Im wanting to write a quick script that can be ran I think downloading the extra library for excel manipulation would be a hassel.

Going to start writing the code today or monday, will probably have more questions later in the week. Thank you everyone for your help! Venturing into new territory with my first job.

Comment: If users are on Excel, why not use VBA (if the logic is not too complicated) or a .net language? Even vba can can bring fairly good performance if you follow basic performance guidelines (especially with such a small file). And your users won't need to open your program separately or save their data in CSV and import it back.

Comment: Well this would be implemented by our IT team and basically we would be ripping a giant database of our printers and then I'd be adding necessary IT data and uploading it myself to our help desk program (via CSV) so no actual user will be messing with it. Its my own project and Ill be the one uploading it every month.

Comment: Part of the reason I'm using java is because of my lack of experience with other programming languages. Java is my comfort programming language and I can be sure to not make a mistake while programming it in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If reading a CSV is an option in your situation, I would definitely go for it, because you can do it in a way that is both system-independent and portable without using external libraries.

As far as the efficiency goes, the timing is very likely going to be I/O dominated, so the smaller the file - the faster you are going to read it in.

Adding the missing information and writing the file back may be a bit tricky because of the need to properly handle quotes, but it is still a lot simpler than accessing an Excel file through a special-purpose library.

Comment: I would image there are some fixed overheads to reading Excel files due to the object model that needs to be set up. If using apache POI for example there is a considerable construction time for a `WorkBook` object.

Comment: Okay, thats good to know. Its not too large of a file, it'll be approx 500 x 10 cells in excel. I didn't realize you had to download a jxl library for excel.

Comment: One more question, if you have access to an excel file wouldnt you always be able to get access to a CSV file since excel has the option to save / export it as a CSV file?

Comment: @BoristheSpider This depends on the implementation of the Excel reader. You're definitely right on that the overhead of the Excel is going to be higher, but since it's a small file that fits in memory, reading it from disk will probably dominate anyway.

Comment: @TacticallySuperiorAvocado The `CSV` file would be independent from the Excel file, in the sense that the end-user would have to manually open Excel, save as CSV, run your program, and treat its result as a CSV file independent from the original Excel file.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I understand, Im just now getting into the whole programming world in a company / database sense so Im writing a fairly small program that is just meant to facilitate our data flow for our help desk.

I have to get used to thinking about the end user (even though in this case I would be the end user, or another IT guy).

Answer (score 2):

CSV willl be easier since you do not need any additional libraries like jxl. Refer to this [read and write CSV tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

500x10 is really quite small so difficult to imagine a lot of code would be required. If sticking with Excel its inbuilt features (Find/Replace, Sort, Filter, PivotTable, Copy down etc) I would expect to be sufficient.